# GS Error : Can't use Object streams before PDF 1.5, ignoring WriteObjStms directive

Tags: ghostscript

I am trying to compress my pdf files dates back to 2010 using GhostScript on Windows 10 E machine via CLI/CMD line as below,

`gswin64c -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=144 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=144 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=144 -sOutputFile=${1%.*}.compressed.pdf BOOK1.pdf`

But unfornately I am getting following errors with it. What could be the reason? COuld you please help?

````
GPL Ghostscript 10.03.0: Can't use an XRef stream before PDF 1.5, ignoring WriteXRefStm directive
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.```
````

Comment: @KJ - I made it like this now, `>gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=compressed.pdf BOOK1.pdf` . But now I am getting error like,  `Error: Couldn't initialise file.
               Output may be incorrect.
   No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage)`

Comment: The latest version of pdfwrite defaults to writing ObjStm and XRef stream objects in PDF files. These were introduced with PDF 1.5 so if you set the CompatibilityLevel below that (and you have set 1.3) then they can't be used. An oversight (since fixed) means that the warning (**not** an error) is issued anyway. It has no other effect. Whatever is causing the inability to open the device, it isn't that. If you think you have found a bug you should make a bug report. You should also try reducing the complexity of the command line.

Comment: Note that using ObjStm and XRef stream objects will make many files **much** smaller, so not using them isn't optimal. And, as I keep saying, Ghostscript's pdfwrite device doesn't compress PDF files. It produces new PDF files which may be smaller (and downsampling images will often result sin smaller files) but they aren't 'compressed'.

Comment: <sigh> and you can't use the /Bicubic or /Average downsampling filters with monochrome images, because those filters rely on creating values intermediate between the original values. Since monochrome images only have black and white pixels it is not possible to create an intermediate value. That should produce a warning if you ever trigger it, ,telling you that pdfwrite is ignoring the requested filter and using the Subsample filter.